# Selenium can't find WebElements when trying to use headless chromedriver option

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am running selenium with chromedriver and it all works fine.
Lately I tried to work with 10 chromedrivers simultaneously and it takes all the memory available, so I tried to solve it with headless option in ChromeOptions.

Tried those options:

```
        options.addArguments("--headless");
        options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
        options.addArguments("--window-size=1920,1200");
        options.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
```

But when the program runs with --headless option it won't work. (it worked before without the headless)

this is how I setup my chromeDriver:

```
private ChromeDriver setupChromeDriver(String proxyAddress, String downloadFilePath){
        try{
            HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<>();
            chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
            chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadFilePath);
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
            options.addArguments("--headless");
            options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
            options.addArguments("--window-size=1920,1200");
            options.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
            DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
            cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
            cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
            if(!proxyAddress.equals(""))
                cap.setCapability("proxy", setupChromeProxy(proxyAddress));
            ChromeDriverService chromeDriverService = new ChromeDriverService.Builder().build();
            options.merge(cap);
            logger.info("Selenium chrome driver set up with updated download location");
            return new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverService, options);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            logger.info(e.getMessage());
            logger.info(BaseUtilities.getStackTrace(e));
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

example how I find element which works without the headless option:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='identifierId']")).sendKeys(dumper.getUsername() + Keys.ENTER);
```

I am using Windows 10, chrome Version 75.0.3770.142 (Official Build) (64-bit),
ChromeDriver 75.0.3770.140

Tried to find some information in similar posts but couldn't find a working solution.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply try like this

```
    ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");

    WebDriver wDriver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```